Is a lift of a uniformly continuous function along a finite regular cover uniformly continuous?
Suppose $(M,d)$ is a metric space and $G$ is a finite group acting freely on $M$ by isometries.
Assume further that the quotient $M/G$ inherits a metric $\overline{d}$ for which the projection $p:M \rightarrow M/G$ is a local isometry.
Question: Suppose $f:M/G \rightarrow M/G$ is a uniformly continuous function.  Does it follow that any lift $\widetilde{f}:M \rightarrow M$ is uniformly continuous?
If not, what if we assume that $f$ is a homeomorphism with a uniformly continuous inverse, and/or that $M$ is a smooth manifold with a Riemannian metric?

No, here are two counterexamples.
Counterexample 1. Let $M = (\mathbb{R} - \{0\}) \times \{-1, 1\}$ be the union of two punctured lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and let $G = \mathbb{Z} / 2$ act on $M$ by reflection across the $x$-axis. Then $M / G \cong \mathbb{R} - \{0\}$. Let $\tilde{f} : M \to M$ be the map given by
$$
\tilde{f}(x, t) = \begin{cases}
(x, t) & \text{if $x > 0$,} \\
(x, -t) & \text{if $x < 0$.}
\end{cases}
$$
Then $\tilde{f}$ lifts the identity map but is not uniformly continuous.
The next counterexample demonstrates that completeness is not the issue.
Counterexample 2. Let
$$
M = \{(x, t) \in \mathbb{R} \times \{0, 1\} \mid x = n + 1 / m \ \text{for} \ n \in \mathbb{Z}, m \in \mathbb{Z}_{> 0}\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2,
$$
and let $G$ be as above. Define $\tilde{f} : M \to M$ by
$$
\tilde{f}(n + 1 / m, t) = \begin{cases}
(x, -t) & \text{if $1 < m < n$,} \\
(x, t) & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
Again, $\tilde{f}$ lifts the identity map but is not uniformly continuous.

I suspect the answer may be yes when $M$ is a connected Riemannian manifold (if $M$ is not connected, there is no canonical metric space structure), but I don't have a proof.
